# how to set progress bar during copying file from one folder to another in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, copy, progress-bar

Currently I'm doing project in vb.net and I want to set the progress bar while copying files from one folder to another. And the progress bar should move towards completion according to amount of file copied.

Comment: Note for readers looking for a solution where an individual progress indicator PER FILE will be enough : `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(OldLocation, NewLocation, FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)` will show the standard Windows copying display.

Answer (score 3):

Not so new question, but here's an answer nonetheless.  The following code will achieve the desired result whereby an individual file's progress is tracked.  It uses a 1 MiB buffer.  Depending on your system's resources, you can adjust the buffer accordingly to tweak the performance of the transfer.

**Concept:** Count each byte as it is read/written and report the progress based on the total size of the source file, using file streams.

```
'Create the file stream for the source file
Dim streamRead as New System.IO.FileStream([sourceFile], System.IO.FileMode.Open)
'Create the file stream for the destination file
Dim streamWrite as New System.IO.FileStream([targetFile], System.IO.FileMode.Create)
'Determine the size in bytes of the source file (-1 as our position starts at 0)
Dim lngLen as Long = streamRead.Length - 1
Dim byteBuffer(1048576) as Byte   'our stream buffer
Dim intBytesRead as Integer    'number of bytes read

While streamRead.Position < lngLen    'keep streaming until EOF
    'Read from the Source
    intBytesRead = (streamRead.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 1048576))
    'Write to the Target
    streamWrite.Write(byteBuffer, 0, intBytesRead)
    'Display the progress
    ProgressBar1.Value = CInt(streamRead.Position / lngLen * 100)
    Application.DoEvents()    'do it
End While

'Clean up 
streamWrite.Flush()
streamWrite.Close()
streamRead.Close()
```

Comment: This is great! Would it be possible to also get a real-time output to a label of the bytes transferred? 
Thank you!

Comment: @SilverSlash, it is entirely possible.  Since this solution uses a 1 MiB buffer, it would be accurate to the nearest MiB.  Just like `streamRead.Position` is used to calculate the progress bar value, it can be used to display the number of bytes already processed.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? I changed my byte buffer to (4096). Thank you.

Comment: Assuming you have a label named `lblBytesRead`, you would just have to add `lblBytesRead.Text = streamRead.Position` just before `Application.DoEvents()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Concept used**: Get the `count of files` in the `source directory`, and then whenever `copying` a `file` from `source folder` to `destination folder` increment a `variable` to trace how many `files` get transferred. Now calculate the `files` transferred percentage by using the following formula,

```
% of files transferred = How many files Transferred * 100 / Total No of files in source folder
```

And then after getting the `% of files transferred`, update the progress bar's value by using it.

Try this code : `Tested with IDE`

```
  Dim xNewLocataion = "E:\Test1"

        Dim xFilesCount = Directory.GetFiles("E:\Test").Length
        Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

        For Each xFiles In Directory.GetFiles("E:\Test")

            File.Copy(xFiles, xNewLocataion & "\" & Path.GetFileName(xFiles), True)
            xFilesTransferred += 1

            ProgressBar1.Value = xFilesTransferred * 100 / xFilesCount
            ProgressBar1.Update()

        Next
```

Comment: I'm currently using this thing, but when large files come, it looks like it hangs, so I try to make progress bar working on total size of all selected files, like if total size of 5 files is 100MB then when 50MB is completed the progress bar should be at half no matter how many files has been transferred.