# vb.net copying contents of folders and progress bar

Tags: vb.net

I am attempting to make a backup program to copy files within a directory as well as having a progress bar run throughout the copy process.  I am using the below code.  It looks like the code only copies an actual file, versus everything in the directory.  How do i make the below code copy everything in the directory?

```
 Private Sub backupL01()
       Dim xNewLocataion = My.Settings.dest
        If Not Directory.Exists(xNewLocataion) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(xNewLocataion)
        End If
        Dim xFilesCount = Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.source).Length
        Dim xFilesTransferred As Integer = 0

        For Each xFiles In Directory.GetFiles(My.Settings.source)

            File.Copy(xFiles, xNewLocataion & "\" & Path.GetFileName(xFiles), True)
            xFilesTransferred += 1

            ProgressBar1.Value = xFilesTransferred * 100 / xFilesCount
            ProgressBar1.Update()

            'MsgBox("Backup has been completed.", , "Backup")
            'ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: It is a problem with the progress bar or you have a problem with the copy? I mean, your progress bar doesn't show the correct progression of the copy process?

Comment: Community service: The code originates from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15676163/11683

Comment: it shows the correct progress of the copy, but the copy only copies a file and not all of the folders and files within the directory.  So i have a directory with 1 folder and 1 file, it only copies the 1 file versus everything

Comment: Time to start the debugger. Put a breakpoint before the loop and start step by step looking at the values of your variables.

Comment: to debug what?  theres no error, it runs perfectly fine, it just doesnt COPY EVERYTHING, only 1 file in the directory and not all the folders.

Comment: I think my issue is in this line of code

File.Copy(xFiles, xNewLocataion & "\" & Path.GetFileName(xFiles), True)

Is that copying only files, or everything in the source directory?

Comment: No, your problem is in `Directory.GetFiles`, which (as the name says) gets *files*. If you want to include the directories, you need to use `Directory.GetDirectories`, which (as the name says) gets *directories*. Your code says "get a list of files, and then copy each of those files", and it's doing exactly what you instructed it to do. If you want it to also process directories, then you need to get a list of those directories and deal with them as well.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to use this, it is fine for what im using this for:

```
Dim xNewLocataion = My.Settings.dest
        If Not Directory.Exists(xNewLocataion) Then
            Directory.CreateDirectory(xNewLocataion)
        End If
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(My.Settings.source, My.Settings.dest, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
```