# Issue using elements in a list in FOR EACH loop

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB.net and want to write an application to read a text file with a list of paths, count the number of files in all the paths, copy the everything in the path and show the progress via a progress bar with an eta of completion.

So far I have only the text file being read and the counter working correctly, but cannot work out how to use the paths already stored in `pathlist` list to be the sources in the copy. Here is what I have;

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\CONFIG.txt") = True Then

        Dim pathlist As New List(Of String)

        ' Open config.txt with the Using statement.
        Using r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(Application.StartupPath + "\CONFIG.txt")
            ' Store contents in this String.
            Dim line As String

            ' Read first line.
            line = r.ReadLine

            ' Loop over each line in file, While list is Not Nothing.
            Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
                ' Add this line to list.
                pathlist.Add(line)

                'count the files in the directories as we go through the loop
                counter = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(line, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count()
                'add # of files to overall count
                filecount += counter

               ' Read the next line.
                line = r.ReadLine

            Loop

        End Using

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Config.txt does not exist")
    End If

    'Label Showing total files
    Label1.Text = filecount

       End Sub
```

How would I use the line strings in pathlist to do the following:

1. Copy the folder with all subfile and directories to the destination folder
2. Update a counter so I can use a progress bar
3. Do an time remaining counter, how can this be estimated? Should I be calculating the size in MB's of all the data? Or something similar?

If anyone can assist or link me an example I could use, that would be great!

Comment: The only way you can use a incremental progress bar is if you know the total number of files before hand (even then its wonky: a 100MB file will take longer than a 1k file).  The only way to calculate an eta is to know the total bytes to be moved and count the bytes copies as you go.

Comment: check out this link to see if this can help you! [how to set progress bar during copying file from one folder to another in vb.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675515/how-to-set-progress-bar-during-copying-file-from-one-folder-to-another-in-vb-net)

Comment: Use `Path.Combine()` instead of string concatenation.